# Can I the result that did FetchPage and can do FetchPage more in Yahoo!Pipes?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I do scrape of a page with Yahoo!Pipes and want about scrape doing other pages with this result more.

For example
[FetchPage] -[Regex]
Based on it
[URLBuilder]

I want to do input of URLBuilder in Path, but will such a thing be possible?

Comment: it's not very clear what you want to do, please try to explain better

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Number Input** as an input to the **Fetch Page** (if you want to page from different parts of a page) or **URL Builder** (if the page supports server-side paging)